# Tweet 数の取得方法

Tags: twitter

以前はTwitterのツイート数がボタンから取得できましたが、サポート終了に伴い今は表示されていないかと思います。

このサイトはツイートボタンの横につぶやき数を表示させていますが、どうやって取得しているのでしょうか。http://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/articles/1602/24/news125.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[widgetoon.js & count.jsoon](http://jsoon.digitiminimi.com/)が提供している代替APIを使っているようです。